# Matrix derivative: $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}(\mathbb{A}(\mathbb{A}^T\Sigma\mathbb{A})^{-1}\mathbb{A}^T)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{A} = (A_{ij})$ be a rectangular, $m\times n$ real matrix, full-rank and with $m \le n$. Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a real $n\times n$ symmetric and pos-def matrix. With these assumptions, $\mathbb{A}^T\mathbb{C}\mathbb{A}$ is invertible. Finally, let $\mathbf{u}$ be an $m$-vector.

I need to compute the following derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbb{A}}(\mathbf{u}^T\mathbb{A}(\mathbb{A}^T\mathbb{C}\mathbb{A})^{-1}\mathbb{A}^T\mathbf{u})$$

where $\Sigma$ is considered a constant.

But I keep struggling with the algebra which gets really messy.

Any tricks I can use?

Comment: After taking the inverse and cancelling, doesn't it just reduce to the partial of $\Sigma$?

Comment: @HankIgoe Can you be explicit? Note that I intended $\Sigma$ to be a constant./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some algebra, I arrive at the result:

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbb{A}}(\mathbf{u}^T\mathbb{A}(\mathbb{A}^T\mathbb{C}\mathbb{A})^{-1}\mathbb{A}^T\mathbf{u})
=
\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^{\top} \mathbb{A} (\mathbb{A}^{\top}
\mathbb{C}\mathbb{A})^{- 1} -\mathbb{C}\mathbb{A} (\mathbb{A}^{\top}
\mathbb{C}\mathbb{A})^{- 1} \mathbb{A}^{\top} \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^{\top}
\mathbb{A} (\mathbb{A}^{\top} \mathbb{C}\mathbb{A})^{- 1}$$

I also checked this result numerically, using automatic differentiation in Julia (Zygote).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first note$$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}(A^T\Sigma A)_{kl}=\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}(A_{mk}\Sigma_{mn}A_{nl})=\delta_{jk}(\Sigma A)_{il}+(A^T\Sigma)_{ki}\delta_{jl}.$$Define $X_{ijlm}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}(A^T\Sigma A)^{-1}_{lm}$ so$$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}\delta_{km}=[\delta_{jk}(\Sigma A)_{il}+(A^T\Sigma)_{ki}\delta_{jl}](A^T\Sigma A)^{-1}_{lm}+(A^T\Sigma A)_{kl}X_{ijlm}.$$Solve this to get $X_{ijlm}$, then compute $u_ku_n\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}[A_{kl}(A^T\Sigma A)^{-1}_{lm}A_{nm}]$, which is a matrix.

Comment: Please see final edit. I just added a vector to contract, so that the final result is just a matrix.

Comment: @becko I've updated my answer to reflect this. Of course, if you change the vector on the end to not match the one at the start for an easy generalization, we just need to replace $u_n$ with $v_n$ (say).

Comment: I think I found a result in matrix notation which is consistent with your answer.

Comment: @becko Your answer passes obvious sanity checks. It'd be good if you edited your answer to show how you got it. You could even select your own answer once it's 24 or more hours old.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got to it essentially extending from your approach, so I think it should be equivalent. I also checked it numerically with some random matrices.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\R{\mathbb R}\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Consider the matrix-valued function $F$ defined by
$$\eqalign{
S &= \Sigma &\implies\quad S=S^T \\
B &= A^TSA &\implies\quad B=B^T \\
F &= AB^{-1}A^T &\implies\quad F=F^T \\
}$$
and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
dF &= dA\;B^{-1}A^T + AB^{-1}dA^T - AB^{-1}dB\,B^{-1}A^T \\
 &= dA\;B^{-1}A^T + AB^{-1}dA^T \\
 &\quad- AB^{-1}\;dA^TSAB^{-1}A^T - AB^{-1}A^TS\,dA\,B^{-1}A^T \\
 &= dA\;B^{-1}A^T + AB^{-1}dA^T - AB^{-1}\;dA^TSF - FS\,dA\,B^{-1}A^T \\
 &= (I-FS)\;dA\;B^{-1}A^T + AB^{-1}\;dA^T(I-SF) \\
}$$
In order to continue, we'll need the following two gradients
$$\eqalign{
\p{A}{A_{ij}} &= e_i\e_j^T \qquad\quad \p{A^T}{A_{ij}} &= \e_je_i^T \\
}$$
where $\Big\{e_i\in\R^{m},\;\e_j\in\R^{n}\Big\}$ denote the standard basis vectors for the respective dimensions.

Now the gradient can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\p{F}{A_{ij}}
 &= (I-FS)(e_i\e_j^TB^{-1}A^T) + AB^{-1}\e_je_i^T(I-SF) \\
}$$
So that is the answer to the question in the title. However the question in the body of the post concerns the gradient of a *scalar-valued* function $\phi$ with respect to the matrix $A$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= u^TFu \\
d\phi
 &= u^TdF\,u \\
 &= {\rm Trace}(u^TdF\,u) \\
 &= {\rm Trace}(uu^TdF) \\
 &= {\rm Trace}\Big(uu^T(I-FS)\;dA\;B^{-1}A^T\Big)
  + {\rm Trace}\Big(uu^TAB^{-1}\;dA^T(I-SF)\Big) \\
 &= {\rm Trace}\Big(B^{-1}A^Tuu^T(I-FS)\;dA\Big)
  \;+ {\rm Trace}\Big((I-SF)\,uu^TAB^{-1}\;dA^T\Big) \\
 &= {\rm Trace}\Big(2\,(I-SF)\,uu^TAB^{-1}\;dA^T\Big) \\
\p{\phi}{A}
 &= 2\,(I-SF)\,uu^TAB^{-1} \\
}$$